# Access to ResourcePoll Utilization Data set

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to show `ResourcePool` utilization on a Time Plot chart.

Currently I use Time Plot to display by `Value` the utilization of the selected `ResourcePool`:
[image]

My problem is that every time the `stageIndex` changes, the Time Plot resets and starts showing the data from that moment on.

Is there a way to directly access the `DataSet` of the `ResourcePool` (if there is one) and also get the past information about the utilization?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is stages and stageIndex? and what does it have anything to do with resourcepool utilization?

Comment: stages is a population of an agent with ResourcePool. stageIndex is integer variable used as an index to access a specific agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource pools don't store historic utilisation information. (AnyLogic Datasets store time series, but most blocks/elements don't have built-in logic to store such a time series for every numeric statistic calculateable from them...)

The simple (and design best-practice) alternative is to have plots showing the utilisations over time for *all* resource pools you're indexing into and just control the visibility of these plots dynamically (if, as you suggest, the user selects which agent (with embedded resource pool) they want to view the graph for). They could be at identical x,y coords if you want (with only 1 visible) or not.

You can use AnyLogic's **replication** functionality to make this easy in this case: replication is useful when you have multiple charts or presentation elements with a common set of 'rules' regarding their number, placement and properties (including visibility). See the
[2D and 3D animation --> Animating replicated objects](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/presentation/animating-replicated-objects.html) help page. (In particular, this is the only way to have a *dynamic* number of charts/shapes depending on some potentially-changing-over-time and/or determined-only-at-run-time (e.g., related to input data) piece of information.)

**NB:** You could define and populate the historic utilisation Datasets yourself, but you still can't use a single plot because the Dataset expression you enter is effectively static: it is only evaluated once at model start. The "Value" expression is 'dynamic' but only because that's how Value plots work: the expression is evaluated at the interval you specify to 'add the next value to the plot' (which is why the behaviour you observe occurs when you change your index).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.
The solution I made (although it burdens my model a bit) is to use the `replication` parameter of the `TimePlot`.

The # of `replication` is set by `stages.size()`.
And I set the value as `stages(index).resourcePool.utilization()`.

I decides who to display using the `Visible` parameter `stageIndex == index`

Comment: Yes, replication is the way to most easily define multiple charts and presentation elements which share the same 'rules' regarding placement and properties. I'll amend the answer for completeness to include this.

Answer (score 1):

ok so it seems that you have population that removes agents from the population since that's the only reason why the index (assuming you use getIndex()) would change: adding and removing agents from the population

If you do that, you need to save the utilization independently from the agent itself, so you can do that by just using a collection (outside the population) with that information that is updated every certain amount of time with resourcePool.utilization()

since i don't know exactly what you are trying to do, this is all i can say

Comment: I seen that the ```ResourcePool``` block have function ```void resetStats()``` that resets the statistics collected for this block.

So I assume it keeps its historical data, such as ```utilization``` Do I have the option to access this ```DataSet```?

Comment: i just told you how to keep historical data... if you delete the agent, the historical data will not be saved, unless you save it independently from the agent... otherwise.. don't delete agents, and keep them alive somewhere

Comment: I don't delete the agent.

Comment: you said the stageIndex changes... you need to be significantly more specific with what your situation is... otherwise i don't think you will get the help you need

Comment: Yes, ```stageIndex``` is a variable of integer type, its change makes me jump from agent to agent within the population. The agents are not deleted. I just refer each time to a different agent according to the user's choice.

Comment: ok.. in that case, you need to save a dataset of your resourcepool utilization inside the agent and instead of using stage.get(index).resourcePool.utilization you do stage.get(index).dataset ... then you can just use in your graph a dataset instead of a value and calculate the dataset, in which you will save the mean utilization each x amount of time

Comment: Ok, so if you suggest this to me, I can conclude that there is no way for the ResourcePool block to accessed the DataSet with a utilization data?

Comment: not accessible to us as far as i know since the utilization method loops around the resources and calculates the mean, but the resources themselves as individuals don't give us access to their own utilization individually